# Windows 10 guest under libvirt can't use network

Tags: networking, windows, libvirt

I have a libvirt (libvirtd 3.0.0) install with several guest VMs all under kvm.  I'm using bridged networking on the host to allow them full access to the networks.  The host OS is Debian (stretch).

```
auto br0
iface br0 inet static
    bridge_ports eno1
    bridge_stp on
    bridge_waitport 0
    bridge_maxwait 0
    address [redacted]
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway [redacted]
    dns-nameservers [redacted]
```

I just installed a Windows 10 Pro VM (Version 1809, build 17763.379) which does not seem to be able to access the network.  The Windows interface troubleshooter shows no problems with the "hardware" but it's unable to ping the default gateway (same subnet as the host OS).

The host and my other guests are all dual-stack, but for the moment I'm only attempting to configure the Windows guest with IPv4.

My VM's network interface configs are thus:

```
    <interface type='bridge'>
      <mac address='52:54:00:f7:46:de'/>
      <source bridge='br0'/>
      <model type='rtl8139'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
    <interface type='bridge'>
      <mac address='52:54:00:f9:0c:28'/>
      <source bridge='br1'/>
      <model type='rtl8139'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x04' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
```

The OS driver matches the driver listed in the VM's XML definition.

What should I be looking at?

Comment: What is `br1` ?

Comment: A second interface on the internal network.  It suffers from the same issue as `br0`.